# How to handle dependencies from recursive Makefile invocations?

Tags: makefile

I have a C project that consists of a fairly large number of source files, and to make some sense of them, I have put them into subdirectories (with subdirectories). The whole project results in only one executable file, however.

In order to build this project, then, I am using recursive Makefiles, where the Makefile in each non-toplevel directory links all the object files produced in that directory into a concatenated `lib.o` file (using `ld -r`, that is). I do have a Makefile system that can build this and works rather fine for what it is, but it cannot support parallel `make`, which I would like to fix.

The problem is that I cannot figure out a proper way to both force `make` to descend into each directory's subdirectories, but also have the local `lib.o` target depend on that without being forced to rebuild even when nothing has changed.

This is how it works, somewhat abbreviated (leaving out `CFLAGS` and whatnot):

```
default: build

SUBOBJECTS =    $(patsubst %,%/lib.o,$(SUBDIRS))

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
        @$(MAKE) -C $@

build: $(SUBDIRS) lib.o

lib.o: $(OBJECTS) $(SUBOBJECTS)
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -r -o $@ $^
```

This is from a `Makefile.common` which all other Makefiles include. Every other Makefile would also define their own `SUBDIRS` and `OBJECTS`. It might look like this, for instance:

```
SUBDIRS =   dir1 dir2
OBJECTS =   object1.o object2.o

include ../Makefile.common   # Or ../../Makefile.common, &c.
```

As you can see from this, the main target is really the `build` target, which depends on the subdirectories and `lib.o`. If I invoke parallel `make` on this, it won't know that `lib.o` cannot be built until `make` has already run recursively on the subdirectories and will sometimes attempt that, causing errors. However, if I make `lib.o` depend on the subdirectories, then `lib.o` will always be unnecessarily rebuilt on each invocation, in each directory.

Is there a way to solve this? I've wrecked my brains on this for quite a while now without being able to find a way out. I'm only using GNU `make`, so don't worry too much about being POSIX-compatible.

Comment: These situations are why many people recommend non-recursive make.  Having lots of individual make instances all trying to update the _same_ target just doesn't work well.

Comment: @MadScientist: That doesn't sound like my problem, though. I don't have multiple `make` instances updating the same target. :)